# javascript showing .onclick property as null

Tags: javascript, jscript

When I tried to change the .onclick property, it didn't work, so I tried to debug and when I alerted the document.onclick property I found out java script says it's value is null.
Command in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("switch").onclick = "autoSlides(2)";
```

HTML:

```
  <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch" onclick="autoSlides(1)" />
      <div class="slider"></div>
  </label>
```

Full Javascript:

```
function autoSlides(x) {
    var timeOut;
    if (x == 2) {
        timeOut = null;
        document.getElementById("switch").onclick = "autoSlides(1)"
    }
    if (x == 1) {
        plusSlides(1);
        document.getElementById("switch").onclick = "autoSlides(2)";
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () { autoSlides(1) }, 4000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are adding a string to `onclick` event.

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("switch").onclick = "autoSlides(2)";
```

use:

```
document.getElementById("switch").onclick = function() {autoSlides(2)};  // calling a function autoSlides()
```

Comment: As Rick mentioned, it would attach the results of 'autoSlides(2). Plus, if you use function, then it would attach multiple onClick events on the element.